# How do I find common characters between two strings in bash?

Tags: string, bash, shell

For example:

```
s1="my_foo"
s2="not_my_bar"
```

the desired result would be `my_o`. How do I do this in bash?

Comment: the underscore will be the delimiter?

Comment: no, the thing is that I want to get all common characters from s1 and s2

Comment: extreme difference between the simplicity of the task and the complexity of the solution in shell scripting. very nice!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My solution below uses `fold` to break the string into one character per line, `sort` to sort the lists, `comm` to compare the two strings and finally `tr` to delete the new line characters

```
comm -12 <(fold -w1 <<< $s1 | sort -u) <(fold -w1 <<< $s2 | sort -u) | tr -d '\n'
```

Alternatively, here is a pure Bash solution (which also maintains the order of the characters). It iterates over the first string and checks if each character is present in the second string.

```
s="temp_foo_bar"
t="temp_bar"
i=0
while [ $i -ne ${#s} ]
do
    c=${s:$i:1}
    if [[ $result != *$c* && $t == *$c* ]]
    then
      result=$result$c
    fi
    ((i++))
done
echo $result
```

prints: `temp_bar`

Comment: Your second method has the vice of not working with spaces in `t` and `s`. At least in it's current form. Also it's rather lengthy.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the strings do not contain embedded newlines:

```
s1='my_foo' s2='my_bar'
intersect=$(
  comm -12 <(
    fold -w1 <<< "$s1" |
      sort -u
      ) <(
        fold -w1 <<< "$s2" |
          sort -u
          ) |
            tr -d \\n
            )

printf '%s\n' "$intersect"
```

And another one:

```
tr -dc "$s2" <<< "$s1"
```

Comment: Your second solution with `tr` is nice, but doesn't remove duplicates.

Comment: @dogbane, good point! I should have mentioned that. To remove duplicates both values should pass the `fold .. | sort ..` filter.

Answer (score 2):

a late entry, I've just found this page:

```
echo "$str2" |
  awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}
  { n=0; while(n<=NF) {
   if ($n == substr(test,n,1)) { if(!found[$n]) printf("%c",$n); found[$n]=1;} n++;
  } print ""}' test="$str1"
```

and another one, this one builds a regexp for matching (note: doesn't work with special characters, but that's not that hard to fix with anonther sed)

```
echo "$str1" |
  grep -E -o ^`echo -n "$str2" | sed 's/\(.\)/(|\1/g'; echo "$str2" | sed 's/./)/g'`
```

Comment: Good idea to use `awk` but does not work using this example `awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} { n=0; while(n<=NF) {if ($n == substr(test,n,1)) {printf("%c",$n);} n++;} print ""}' test="/aa/ba/" <<< "/aa/bb/"`. It displays `/aa/b/` instead of `/aa/b`. Please try to fix your answer. Cheers

Comment: @olibre: weird report :) fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Should be a portable solution:

```
s1="my_foo"  
s2="my_bar"
while [ -n "$s1" -a -n "$s2" ]
do
    if [ "${s1:0:1}" = "${s2:0:1}" ]
    then
        printf %s "${s1:0:1}"
    else
        break
    fi
    s1="${s1:1:${#s1}}"
    s2="${s2:1:${#s2}}"
done
```

Comment: This only matches characters at the same index in both strings. So won't work if you have `my_foo_bar` and `my_bar`.

Answer (score 1):

```
comm=""
for ((i=0;i<${#s1};i++))
do 
  if test ${s1:$i:1} = ${s2:$i:1}
  then 
    comm=${comm}${s1:$i:1}
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using a single sed execution:

```
echo -e "$s1\n$s2" | sed -e 'N;s/^/\n/;:begin;s/\n\(.\)\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\1\(.*\)/\1\n\2\n\3\4/;t begin;s/\n.\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\n\1\n\2/;t begin;s/\n\n.*//'
```

As all cryptic sed script, it needs explanation in the form of a sed script file that can be run by `echo -e "$s1\n$s2" | sed -f script`:

```
# Read the next line so s1 and s2 are in the pattern space only separated by a \n.
N
# Put a \n at the beginning of the pattern space.
s/^/\n/
# During the script execution, the pattern space will contain <result so far>\n<what left of s1>\n<what left of s2>.
:begin
# If the 1st char of s1 is found in s2, remove it from s1 and s2, append it to the result and do this again until it fails.
s/\n\(.\)\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\1\(.*\)/\1\n\2\n\3\4/
t begin
# When previous substitution fails, remove 1st char of s1 and try again to find 1st char of S1 in s2.
s/\n.\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\n\1\n\2/
t begin
# When previous substitution fails, s1 is empty so remove the \n and what is left of s2.
s/\n\n.*//
```

If you want to remove duplicate, add the following at the end of the script:

```
:end;s/\(.\)\(.*\)\1/\1\2/;t end
```

**Edit:** I realize that dogbane's pure shell solution has the same algorithm, and is probably more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone loves perl one-liners full of punctuation:

`perl -e '$a{$_}++ for split "",shift;  $b{$_}++ for split "",shift;  for (sort keys %a){print if defined $b{$_}}' my_foo not_my_bar`

Creates hashes `%a` and `%b` from the input strings.
Prints any characters common to both strings.

outputs:

```
_moy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"flower","flow","flight" --> output fl

    s="flower"
t="flow"
i=0
while [ $i -ne ${#s} ]
do
    c=${s:$i:1}
    if [[ $result != *$c* && $t == *$c* ]]
    then
      result=$result$c
    fi
    ((i++))
done
echo $result
p=$result
q="flight"
j=0

while [ $j -ne ${#p} ]
do
    c1=${p:$j:1}
    if [[ $result1 != *$c1* && $q == *$c1* ]]
    then
      result1=$result1$c1
    fi
    ((j++))
done
echo $result1
```