# Check if each element of an array is present in a string in bash, ignoring certain characters and order

Tags: arrays, string, bash, comm

On the web I found answers to find if **an** element of array is present in the string. But I want to find if **each** element in the array is present in the string.

eg. `str1 = "This_is_a_big_sentence"`

Initially str2 was like

```
str2 = "Sentence_This_big"
```

Now I wanted to search **if string str1 contains "sentence"&"this"&"big" *(All 3, ignore alphabetic order and case)***

So I used `arr=(${str2//_/ })`
How do i proceed now, I know `comm` command finds intersection, but it needs a sorted list, also I need to ignore _ underscores.

I get my `str2` by finding the extension of a particular type of file using the command

```
    for i in `ls snooze.*`; do echo    $i | cut -d "." -f2 
# Till here i get str2 and need to check as mentioned above. Not sure how to do this, i tried putting str2 as array and now just need to check if all elements of my array occur in str1 (ignore case,order)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. I did try to use [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941924/how-do-i-find-common-characters-between-two-strings-in-bash)

Comment: Work with bash's substitution again. Loop over your str2 entries replacing those in str1 with an empty string and afterwards check if the length' has changed. Something like: `for tofind in ${arr[@]}; do [[ "${#str1}" != "${str1//${tofind}/}" ]]; echo $?; done`. 0 then means found. 1 means not found. you just need to check now the times 0 was returned to evaluate if all str2 substrings were found. hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I wanted to search if string a contains "sentence"&"this"&"big"
>   (All 3, ignore alphabatic order and case)

Here is one approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
str1="This_is_a_big_sentence"
str2="Sentence_This_big"
if ! grep -qvwFf <(sed 's/_/\n/g' <<<${str1,,}) <(sed 's/_/\n/g' <<<${str2,,})
then
    echo "All words present"
else
    echo "Some words missing"
fi
```

#### How it works

- `${str1,,}` returns the string `str1` with all capitals replaced by lower case.
- `sed 's/_/\n/g' <<<${str1,,}` returns the string `str1`, all converted to lower case and with underlines replaced by new lines so that each word is on a new line.
- `<(sed 's/_/\n/g' <<<${str1,,})` returns a file-like object containing all the words in `str1`, each word lower case and on a separate line.

  The creation of file-like objects is called *process substitution*.  It allows us, in this case, to treat the output of a shell command as if it were a file to read.
- `<(sed 's/_/\n/g' <<<${str2,,})` does the same for `str2`.
- Assuming that file1 and file2 each have one word per line, `grep -vwFf file1 file2` removes from file2 every occurrence of a word in file2.  If there are no words left, that means that every word in file2 appears in file1.

  By adding the option `-q`, `grep` will return no output but will set an exit code that we can use in our `if` statement.

  In the actual command, file1 and file2 are replaced by our file-like objects.

  The remaining `grep` options can be understood as follows:

  - `-w` tells `grep` to look for whole words only.
  - `-F` tells `grep` to look for fixed strings, not regular expressions.
  - `-f` tells `grep` to look for the patterns to match in the file (or file-like object) which follows.
  - `-v` tells `grep` to remove (the default is to keep) the words which match.

Comment: `if ! grep -qvwFf <(sed 's/_/\n/g' <<<${str1,,}) <(sed 's/_/\n/g' <<<${str2,,})` why does this line makes everything red in vi editor, any fix for that?

Comment: This bash script is called by a python process using
`subprocess.Popen("myscript.sh " +str1,shell=True)`
But it say: ` Syntax error: "(" unexpected` can anyone help me on this. It works fine if I run `./myscript.sh "str1"`

Comment: ok i got what was the problem, python was using sh shell, rather it should have been using bash shell

Comment: However if  i give brackets like `if [ ! grep -qvwFf <(sed 's/_/\n/g' <<<${str1,,}) <(sed 's/_/\n/g' <<<${str2,,})]
line 28: [: missing `]' I get the missing [] error

Comment: @user1977867 That is because `[` does not belong there.  You have probably observed that `[` often follows `if` but it is actually there only as a special case.  What follows the  `if` in an `if` statement, in general, is a normal shell command (or list of commands).  The `if` statement branches based on the _exit code_ of that command.  `grep` sets a proper exit code and we thus use it as is.  The `[` command is a `test` command.  It is used to set _exit codes_ based on various conditions (a file exists, a string is null, etc.).  We have no use for the `test` command here.

Comment: Thanks @John1024,  for the clear explanation again. I now understand that if we want to test a condition we should use [],  if we have a command or set of commands that finally  return exit code to if should be used without []. Still is there a way to get back vi colour pattern to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach.

```
if [ "$(echo "This_BIG_senTence" | grep -ioE 'this|big|sentence' | wc -l)" == "3" ]; then echo "matched"; fi
```

How it works.
grep options `-i` makes the grep case insensitive, `-E` for extended regular expressions, and `-o` separates the matches by line. Now that it is separated by line use `wc` with `-l` for line count. Since we had 3 conditions we check if it equals 3. Grep will return the lines where the match occurred, so if you are only working with a string, the example above will return the string for each condition, in this case 3, so there won't be any problems.

Note you can also create a grep chain and see if its empty.

```
if [ $(echo "This_BIG_SenTence" | grep -i this | grep -i big | grep -i sentence) ]; then echo matched; else echo not_matched; fi
```

Comment: Thanks@SVTAnthony, but as mentioned in my question, the str1 and are not static, they are extensions of snooze.SOME_TEXT , which i get through ls command `ls snooze.*` the text is not fixed nither its length is fixed to 3

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awk solution to check existence of all the words from a string in another string:

```
str1="This_is_a_big_sentence"
str2="Sentence_This_big"

awk -v RS=_ 'FNR==NR{a[tolower($1)]; next} {delete a[tolower($1)]} END{print (length(a)) ? "Not all words" : "All words"}' <(echo "$str2") <(echo "$str1")
```

With indentation:

```
awk -v RS=_ 'FNR==NR {
   a[tolower($1)]; 
   next
}
{ delete a[tolower($1)] }
END {
   print (length(a)) ? "Not all words" : "All words"
}' <(echo "$str2") <(echo "$str1")
```

**Explanation:**

- `-v RS=_` We use record separator as `_`
- `FNR==NR` - Execute this block for `str2`
- `a[tolower($1)]; next` - Populate an array `a` with each lowercase word as key
- `{delete a[tolower($1)]}` - For each word in `str1` delete key in array `a`
- `END` - If length of array `a` is still not 0 then there are some words left.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
str1="This_is_a_big_sentence"
str2="sentence_This_big"
var=0
var2=0

while read in
do
        if [  $(echo $str1 | grep -ioE $in) ]
        then
                var=$((var+1))
        fi
        var2=$((var2+1))
done < <(echo $str2 | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/' -e 's/_/\n/g')

if [[ $var -eq $var2 && $var -ne 0 ]]
then
        echo "matched"
else
        echo "not matched"
```

What this script does make *str2* all lower case with `sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/'` which is a substitution of any character with its lower case, then replace underscores `_` with return lines `\n` with the following sed expression: `sed -e 's/_/\n/g'`, which is another substitution.

Now the individual words are fed into a while loop that compares *str1* with the word that was fed in. Every time there's a match, increment *var* and every time we iterate though the while, we increment *var2*. If `var == var2`, then all the words of *str2* were found in *str1*. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Now I know what you mean.  Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# add 4 non-matching examples
> snooze.foo_bar
> snooze.bar_go
> snooze.go_foo
> snooze.no_match

# add 3 matching examples
> snooze.foo_bar_go
> snooze.goXX_XXfoo_XXbarXX
> snooze.bar_go_foo_Ok

str1=("foo" "bar" "go")
for i in `ls snooze.*`; do
    str2=${i#snooze.}
    j=0
    found=1
    while [[ $j -lt ${#str1[@]} ]]; do
       if ! echo $str2 | eval grep \${str1[$j]} >& /dev/null; then
           found=0
           break
       fi
       ((j++))
    done
    if [[ $found -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo Match found: $str2
    fi
done
```

Resulting print of this script:

```
Match found: bar_go_foo_Ok
Match found: foo_bar_go
Match found: goXX_XXfoo_XXbarXX
```

alternatively, the if..grep line above can be replaced by

```
if [[ ! $str2 =~  `eval echo \${str1[$j]}` ]]; then
```

utilizing bash's regular expression match.

Note: I am not too careful about special characters in the search string, such as "\" or " " (space), which may cause problem.

**--- Some explanations ---**

In the if .. grep line, $j is first evaluated to the running index, from 0 to the number of elements in $str1 minus 1.  Then, eval will re-evaluate the whole `grep` command again, causing ${str1[jjj]} to be re-evaluated (Here, jjj is the already evaluated index)

The strategy is to set found=1 (found by default), and then when any `grep` fails, we set found to 0 and break the inner j-loop.

Everything else should be straightforward.